# Run an exe in Powershell and close the cmd promt once the exe is executed

Tags: powershell

Hi I want to execute a exe from powershell script. Which I am doing as:

```
[Diagnostics.Process]::Start("$Exepath")
```

However after the execution the cmd window does not close, What to do to close the cmd window and execute rest of the script?

Comment: Why don't you use Start-Process?

Comment: i don't understand clearly you want to run cm and then start some process and after that close it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this :

```
start-process $exepath
```

and if you want to run process form CMD use this :

```
Start-Process cmd "/c start calc"
```